# ¿Mi APK construida con android studio me da problemas no me deja instalarla en otros dispositivos?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

Construyo mi APK sin ningún problema ya sea la `debug` o la `release`, las dos se construyen sin problema, pero cuando quiero instalarlas en otro dispositivo no me deja intento instalar las dos y me dicen que ha error al verificar los paquetes.

**Cabe menciona que ya active la opción de "instalar apps de orígenes desconocidos"**

Alguien me puede ayudar, si la corro en mi teléfono celular desde android studio funciona muy bien, pero la quiero instalar en una tables MarquisMp977, y no me deja me despliega el error de verificación de paquetes

Comment: No hay problema con tu apk. En el dispositivo hay que buscar en la configuración y habilitar origenes desconocidos.

Comment: Ya active la configuracion de origenes desconocidos y sigo con el mismo problema, tambien intente parcharla como en unos videos de internet y NADA ayuda

Comment: Perdon, pensé que el error era que salia el mensaje de origienes desconocidos. Leyendo de vuelta, fijate si el nivel de api mínimo para el que estás compilando contempla el celular donde lo queres instalar, y que en el codigo no tengas partes que solo corren con las apis mas nuevas. Android Studio te lo marca como un aviso: "tal metodo solo esta disponible para api 23 y el minimu de tu aplicación es 19" por ejemplo.

Comment: Y sino fijate corriendolo en modo debug y pone acá los errores con los que se para la aplicación o no se puede instalar.

Comment: Yo creo que estas intentando instalar una release luego de haber instalado una debug y en ese caso debes desinstalar la debug de tu android antes de instalar la firmada

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero siempre agregues la descripción del error tal y como se presenta.

Esto puede ser porque el .apk instalado se firmo con otra keystore (seguramente de debug), o tu dispositivo tiene varias sesiones de usuario, una de la cual instalo la aplicación.

Eliminala, si no puedes eliminarla, ve a configuración > aplicaciones, entra y en la esquina superior derecha selecciona la opción "Uninstall for all users"

Este es un ejemplo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]